# Django Backend with two different data sources

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, django, react-native

I am working on a React web app that will enable the user to store new data rows and edit/udpate old data rows. The reference data, for the React form, is stored in ADLS Gen1 parquet format and the app will write data to a different ADLS location in parquet format.

The question is: How can I setup the Django backend with these two different data source? I want to read some reference data from ADLS Gen1 and write and edit into another ADLS in parquet format.

Answer (score 1):

You can use different databases in django settings like this below :

```
DATABASES = {
    'DB1': {
        'ENGINE': 'mssql',
        'NAME': 'DB_NAME',
        'USER': 'sa',
        'PASSWORD': 'PASSWORD',
        'HOST': 'HOST',
        'PORT': '',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'driver': 'ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server',
        },
    },
    'DB2': {
        'ENGINE': 'mssql',
        'NAME': 'DB_NAME',
        'USER': 'sa',
        'PASSWORD': 'PASSWORD',
        'HOST': 'HOST',
        'PORT': '',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'driver': 'ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server',
        },
    },
}
```

Then on your ORM you can use `tbl.objects.using('DB1').all()`